# spring mvc truncating special symbols

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

We have an application created in spring-boot. We have a rest controller in place as below

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "getDataFromSpaceForTypeForSpaceId/{gridName}/{spaceName}/{dataType}/{spaceId}", method = GET, produces = "application/json")
    public DetailedJsonView getDataFromSpaceForTypeForSpaceId(@PathVariable String spaceId,
                                                              @PathVariable String dataType,
                                                              @PathVariable String gridName,
                                                              @PathVariable String spaceName) throws Exception {
        Object detailedObject = spaceAccessorService.getDetailedDataFromSpaceForTypeNameWithSpaceId(gridName, spaceName, dataType, spaceId);

        String detailedXml = ObjectMarshallarService.marshal(detailedObject);
        return new DetailedJsonView(detailedXml);
    }
```

for the urls like this it works fine

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/query/getDataFromSpaceForTypeForSpaceId/COLO/gcmmprivateSpace/com.ambuj.ValuationSliceRun/InterestRates
```

for the urls like this the last variable spaceId

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/query/getDataFromSpaceForTypeForSpaceId/COLO/gcmmprivateSpace/com.ambuj.ValuationSliceRun/InterestRates#MUREX:RATES:EMEA:2015-01-01
```

Now what we see on the above url is that spaceId comes as InterestRates instead of InterestRates#MUREX:RATES:EMEA:2015-01-01.

I am not sure how i can resolve that

Comment: Encode the property... `#` is to indicate that the part after that is an anchor which is only relevant on the client side. Basically you need to encode every parameter value as it will also break for other high end (like '@' and '&') values. You need to URL encode the values before submitting them.

Comment: you have to encode the url in the calling front, lets say you re making the call in Ajax then you must encode the url by calling the method encodeURIComponent in javascript before making the Ajax call.